# IIS Rewrite Rule for non exsting directory to root for a specific page

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-8

Here is the situation:

www.mydomain.com/anydirectory/specificwebpage should go to www.mydomain.com/specificwebpage without changing the url in the browser.

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
     <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="dir">
                <add key=".*/test.cfm" value="test.cfm" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for dir" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{dir:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" 
          />
            </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

Created a rewrite map for the specific webpage and used a wildcard for the non-existent directory.

/(.*)/test.test -----> /test.test

Thanking you in advance for your help guys.

Re

Comment: Rewrite map is for exact URLs, so you cannot use `.*/test.cfm`. Modify `url` in match tag to perform the check of page name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try and get back

Comment: Having no luck, can someone please help me on this?